# discord py - Bot ignores "if" check

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a weird problem and can't find a solution for it. I want to get the best user from my JSON leaderboard and it's working. But now I want to check if the message.author and the user from the leaderboard have the same User-ID. If yes, then an action should run.

My code:

```
with open("level.json", "r") as a:
     level = json.load(a)
     high_score_list = sorted(level, key=lambda x: level[x].get('secXP'), reverse=True)
     print(f"User2: {high_score_list[0]} + msg author: {message.author.id} - {message.author.name}")
     # thats not working
     if message.author.id == high_score_list[0]:
        embed.set_author(name=f'best leaderboard user!)
        embed.color = 0x686de0
```

Even if the User-IDs are the exact same from the if check, the bot doesn't do it. I tried "print" Lines at the if check, but even this is not running.

Comment: Check if they are the same ttype: `type(message.author.id) == type(high_score_list[0])` Should return `true`

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume your issue is with datatypes. Check your json whether the highscorelist has text or number entries. The author's id is always of type `int` so if your highscore is a `string` they won't ever be equal.

Comment: so should i try `if message.author.id == int(high_score_list[0]):`?